# What's the best/easiest way to create a usb connection from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, usb, usb-drive, socat

I'm wondering what's the best way for me to setup a usb connection from Windows to a remote linux servers (Redhat)? I did some Googling and found socat but that was for Linux to Linux, any ideas?

My objective: To ensure my Yubikey is detected on a remote server, to do this I need to ensure I can create the usb connection and send it to the remote server

Thanks!
Stduong

Comment: A USB connection? As far as I know, socat works mostly with different sorts of sockets, not USB devices. Though Yubikeys show up as keyboards, so unless you're programming them, you don't even need to consider the USB stuff. So, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: You heard of usb on network before? Such as detecting my device on a remote server via my USB port?

Comment: doesn't really even matter if I've heard of it or not, I can well imagine tunneling access to the USB device through a network. Just that as far as I can tell, socat doesn't do that, and you're not really showing how you'd do it. But if it works for you, then it's all fine.